# Почему возникает ошибка 403 при использовании dektrium/yii2-rbac

Tags: yii2

Установил это расширение https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-rbac. Больше ни чего не делал. Теперь пытаюсь войти на страницы с его админкой по этим адресам

`/rbac/permission/index
rbac/role/index
 rbac/rule/index`
В ответ получаю

```
Forbidden (#403)

Вам не разрешено производить данное действие.
```

документации ноль в Issues и на форумах отписался пока ответов нет может поможете в чем проблема?

Comment: Прошу вас ответить на собственный вопрос, т.к. столкнулся с точно такой же проблемой и буду очень вам благодарен за разьяснение!!! Просто ума не приложу как хотя бы сделать 1 акк админским и, как я понял, через него наделять ролями...

Comment: @OlegShleif собственно все.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вылечилась так в common/main.php  в настройках модуля надо указать логин администратора в коде ниже  в место `'adminLogin1','adminLogin2'` указать своего или своих.

```
'user' => [
            'class' => 'dektrium\user\Module',
            'adminPermission' => 'role, permission',
            'admins'=>['adminLogin1','adminLogin2'],
        ],
```

Comment: `ReflectionException
Class dektrium\user\Module does not exist`

Может потому что я пытаюсь использовать модуль без yii2-user??

Comment: Можете подсказать как быть?

Comment: @OlegShleif мне кажется эти два дополнения связаны друг с другом вот кстате ветка на форуме от автора http://yiiframework.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=16660&hilit=yii2+user может ему проше задать вопрос я на гите ему задавал вопросы (гугл переводик в полне подойдет) он отвечал. Мне кажется что вот эта фраза Integrated with Yii2-user - flexible user management module на гите объясняет все.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь) Тогда разберусь со стандартным rbac

Comment: @OlegShleif посмотрите вот это расширение https://github.com/developeruz/yii2-db-rbac

Comment: Спасибо большое, вроде все подробно описано. На этот проект костыльнул... Но думаю для будущих - понадобиться. Премного благодарен!